# Why doesnt tap event work on tablet in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas why the tap event on tablet does not work in the same manner as the click on the desktop in the below example?
On click inside div with class pq, the div should be made red and on click outside the div with class pq all the divs with class pq should become white. Click works on desktop but the same logic with tap doesnt on tablet

```
<div class="pq">
paragraph1
</div>
<div class="pq">
paragraph2
</div>
<div class="pq">
paragraph3
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>


$(document).click(function (e) {
        $('.pq').css("background-color", "white");
        if ($(e.target).hasClass("pq")) {
                $(e.target).css("background-color", "red");
            }
    });




$(document).tap(function (e) {
        $('.pq').css("background-color", "white");
        if ($(e.target).hasClass("pq")) {
                $(e.target).css("background-color", "red");
            }
    });
```

Can run example here: https://jsfiddle.net/f2j7g92d/

Comment: I think for the tap event you need jQuery mobile, and even then, you cannot define it directly as click.

[link](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)

Comment: Thanks Ace, I added <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> but still doesnt work

Comment: @AnnaHmd Remember to make sure the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to include this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"><script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`

into your script, if it still doesn't work I'd advise you to [this](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) website.